How to contact the consulate general of Italy in Chicago?
I need to apply for a long term study visa (type D) at the consulate general of Italy in Chicago, probably the most ridiculously unresponsive consulate I have ever seen. First of all, getting a visa appointment itself seems impossible. They accept mail in applications so I sent them the relevant documents via mail (it was accepted by the consulate) and it has been three weeks without any sort of update. The phone numbers on their website essentially do not work, they just send you to voicemail. Emailing them results in the same situation- all automated replies. I have other pre-planned travel coming up soon and need my passport back but I have no idea what is the status of my visa, i.e whether it's going to take more time or it's rejected. Does anybody know if I can just show up at the consulate and tell them of my situation in hope of a solution?

Holidays? Try to contact the embassy to get informations

@GiacomoCatenazzi, contact the embassy how? OP discribes all methodes and with non they get to speak with a person or get an answer from a person.

You did try leaving a voicemail, I assume?

Note that tomorrow is a public holiday in Italy, and many Italians take the whole week off as holidays; many firms are closed in mid-August, as well as schools and universities. Most of Italy stops for ferragosto, and I wouldn't find it strange if the embassy followed suit. This is possibly the worst time of the year to contact an Italian office, apart from the week between Christmas and New Year's Eve.

@Willeke: the OP try to contact the Chicago consulate, not the main office (which it is responsible for Chicago) in Washington. Or I miss something?

I got an email response today from the consulate in Chicago that they have begun processing my application (after 3 weeks of emailing them). There has to be a better way to go about this- one cannot be this unresponsive when the person concerned is an immigrant who is sending primary identification document which is also the visa document for USA.
@GiacomoCatenazzi I contacted the foreign mission in Rome who said that Chicago consulate is the only one responsible for all clarifications, they did not mention the mission at Washington.

@FedericoPoloni I did send the application around mid july and was hoping it would be done before everyone goes for the holiday period. My institute in Italy very clearly stated they will be working in reduced capacity in August so any visa queries and requirements must be intimated to them before August. So I was under the impression if I avoid August, I should be good.

To help set some expectations, my own student visa application took around 4 months to complete. @FedericoPoloni is correct, you can right-off August as nothing will happen. There has to be a better way to go about this There is, but through a mix of bureaucracy, inertia, and incompetence, the system resists any change that would actually benefit immigrants. I would recommend tracking down the relevant secretary at your institute and CC them on progress. When inevitably this affects your studies you will want some kind of paper trail to show the difficulties you faced.

How did this all work out in the end?
